# How to find node with no incoming relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relationship, cypher, neo4jphp

I am having 2 node types lets say of type 'Student' and 'Teacher'

```
Student have {id, name}.
Teacher have {id, name}.
```

Student can have optional relationship with Class node as 'TEACHES'.

```
(t:Teacher)-[r:TEACHES]->(c:Student).

[r:TEACHES] - Optional relationship. (present or may not present)
```

I want to find "Student" nodes who don't have teacher. i.e There is no any incoming relationship "TEACHES"

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple data setup, along with the query at the bottom you need to solve your problem.  Essentially, you want to query for situations where a relationship doesn't exist.   The syntax here is for neo4j 2.0, so the answer would be slightly different for older versions.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ create (t:Teacher {name:"Bob"})-[r:TEACHES]->(s:Student {name:"Mary"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 2
Relationships created: 1
Properties set: 2
Labels added: 2
19 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ create (t:Teacher {name:"Mark"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
5 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (s:Student) WHERE NOT (s)<-[:TEACHES]-(:Teacher) RETURN s
```

Comment: I wanted to find "Student" nodes who don't have teacher. Thanks for help.

Comment: Just run the query in the opposite direction:   match (s:Student) where not (s)<-[:TEACHES]-() return s;

Answer (score 12):

I think you're looking for this sort of pattern.

```
MATCH (s:Student)
WHERE NOT (s)<-[:TEACHES]-(:Teacher)
RETURN s
```

Answer (score 1):

I got result by this. First match student criteria and then find relationship is null

```
MATCH (s:Student)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t:Teacher)-[r:TEACHES]->(s)
WITH s,r
WHERE r IS NULL
RETURN s.name
```

Comment: You could profile this query and compare to Wes', I think his is probably more straightforward (and I'd drop the `:Teacher` label unless you have non-teacher nodes that also `-[:TEACH]->` student-nodes).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Neo4j version 5+

This query will help you to find the all nodes which don't have any relationship.

```
match (n) where not (n)--() return n;
```

There is other option as well:

```
match(n)
optional match (n)-[r]-()
with id(n) as node, collect({id: id(r), type: type(r), startNode: id(startNode(r)), endNode: id(endNode(r))}) as rel
return {node: node, relationships: rel}
```

It will give you a list of each node that includes its relationships. Nodes without relationship will return as null for the node.